# I have a problem adding a Text to a Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and new to programming in general. My problem is I can't add this

> ```
> child: Align(
>                 alignment: Alignment(0, 48),
>                   child: Text(
>                 'SETS',
>                 style: TextStyle(
>                     fontWeight: FontWeight._(4),
>                     fontSize: 18.0,
>                     fontFamily: 'Roboto',
>                     color: Color(0xFF494949)),
>
>               )),
> ```

to this code

> ```
> class _SetupState extends State<Setup> {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Column(children: [
>       Align(
>           alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
>           child: SizedBox(
>             height: 350.0,
>             width: 350.0,
>
>             child: Container(
>               margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
>               padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
>               decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
>                 color: Color(0xFFE3E3E3),
>               ),
>
>               child: Align(
>                 alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
>                   child: Text(
>                 'SET UP YOUR WORKOUT',
>                 style: TextStyle(
>                     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                     fontSize: 20.0,
>                     fontFamily: 'Roboto',
>                     color: Color(0xFF494949)),
>               )),
>             ),
>           )),
>     ]);
>   }
> }
> ```

I tried adding it to the container, making a new align but I still didn't manage to succeed.
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What's the problem? Also, Change `FontWeight._(4)` to `FontWeight.w400`.

Comment: i don t know how to add that text to the box

Comment: I didn't quite get what's the problem but add a `Column` as a child of the `Container` and add the `Text` widgets as the children of the `Column`.

Comment: like this ? child: Container(
         
              ),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Text(
                    'SET UP YOUR WORKOUT',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                        color: Color(0xFF494949)),
                  )),
              child: Column()
            ),

Comment: If you want the `Text` to be in the `Column` (`return Column...`) then just add it to the `Column`'s children: `Column(children: [Text('SETS',...`.

Comment: If it's not what you want, please add a sample image of what you mean. Also, wrap the `Column` with a `Scaffold`: `return Scaffold(body: Column(...`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7H1UgAF 
this is what I want to do

Comment: that is the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a layout based on the image provided in the comments:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 350.0,
          width: 350.0,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              color: Color(0xFFE3E3E3),
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'SET UP YOUR WORKOUT',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      color: Color(0xFF494949)),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'SETS',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          color: Color(0xFF494949)),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                              Icons.add
                          ),
                          Icon(
                              Icons.remove
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'WORKS',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          color: Color(0xFF494949)),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                              Icons.add
                          ),
                          Icon(
                              Icons.remove
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'RESTS',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          color: Color(0xFF494949)),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                              Icons.add
                          ),
                          Icon(
                              Icons.remove
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.greenAccent,
                        child: Text(
                            'START',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                        },
                        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I used a `Column`(let's name it column1) for the whole grey box, and every one of (SETS, +, -), (WORK, +, -), and (RESTS, +, -) is a `Column` inside the column1. Every (+, -) is a `Row` wrapped with a `Padding`. The `Padding` is used to make the (+, -) become closer to the center of the box.

There are many ways to make such layout, this is only one.

Result:

[image: res]

Answer (score 0):

if that does not work you can first align it the way you want. Then use padding or margin so that you can have it exactly where you want it be.

```
Container(
 padding:
 alignment:
 child:Text()
 )
```